# change API Parameter on Power BI online

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am trying to use data from an Web API with this URL:

http://54.207.13.112/bi/bigdata.php?base=XXXXXXXXXXecleticamaster&tabela=vendas&data_ini=042021&data_fim=122023&usuario=XXXXXXXXXX&senha=XXXXXXXX&nova_conexao=false

To create the dashboard on PBI Desktop I use the parameter TRUE. With this we take a month of data just to create de dashboards. To take all the data we need to change the parameter to FALSE and update only 1AM to 3AM.

Who can I change this? If a change before upload to PBI online its loose the data.

I tried to create a parameter in PBI Desktop, but I don't know how to use this in the URL.